# How to create "coverage-clover" xml file into magento 2

Tags: php, code-coverage, magento2

I want to create "coverage-clover" XML file for whole magento 2 project.
I am using below command:

`php vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit -c dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml --coverage-clover report\`

Comment: And what is your question? and what is the current output and what is the desired output?

Comment: I have coverage-clover xml file now how to use it on Magento 2  sonarqube for  code coverage.